# Error when using sed

Tags: sed

I am trying to write this command on UNIX:

```
ls -l | sed 'p/^.rwx'
```

But I get the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: extra characters after command
```

I'm trying to print the files/dirs in which the user has all the permitions (rwx)

Comment: can you add a description of what you are trying to do with that command? also, [parsing ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) probably not a good choice here

Comment: I'm trying to print the files/dirs in which the user has all the permitions (rwx)

Comment: click https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/364193/edit and add that information to your question...

Comment: The `/p` goes at the end of the sed command, not the beginning. `sed -n /pattern/ p`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `p`rint command needs to come at the end, and you also want to suppress printing by default:

```
ls -l | sed -n '/^.rwx/p'
```

If you're on a system with the `stat` command, there's another way to solve the problem:

```
for f in *
do
  stat -c "%a" "$f" | grep -q ^7 && printf "%s\n" "$f"
done
```

It's dangerous to rely on the output of `ls`; consider someone who created a file like this:

```
touch $'foo\n-rwx some file'
```

... that will create a separate line in the `ls` output that (falsely) matches the regular expression. Using a shell glob (`*`) avoids that issue.

Yet another way is to use `find`:

```
find . ! -name . -prune -perm -700 -ls
```

Comment: I don't encourage using `ls` for anything other than human consumption but for the record (and contrary to popular belief) there are cases when you can safely "parse" `ls` output - this is just one of them (another one that comes to mind is when you want to count items in a directory). So, you can simply do `ls -lq | sed '/^.rwx/!d'` and it will work with any kind of file name.

Comment: good point with the `-q` flag -- that gets around the filename issue. Thanks, Don!

Answer (score 0):

For your specific [problem](http://xyproblem.info/), consider using

```
find . -perms 700 -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

or

```
find . -perms /u+rwx -maxdepth 1 -ls
```

[Reference](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/12/find-files-based-on-their-permissions.html).

Comment: this will recurse subdirectories (different from their original `ls -l`) and I think you want `-700` and maybe `-ls`, to emulate the original `ls -l` behavior.

Comment: And I have to use sed...

Comment: @JeffSchaller: good points. Updated my answer to include `-maxdepth 1` and `-ls`.

Comment: @M.T ok, I just provided an alternative because you didn't specify it was a requirement to use `sed`.

Answer (score -1):

You want to run this:

```
ls -l | sed -n '/^.rwx/p'
```

n -> Prints only matching data

^.rwx -> Starting with any character but followed by rwx.

p -> Print the data

Comment: Can you please explain your answers, add some details

Comment: ls -l | sed -n '/^.rwx/p'

n -> Prints only matching data

^.rwx -> Starting with any character but followed by rwx.

p -> Print the data